# How to retrieve email addresses and names from a string and insert them into a HTML table using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains names (firstname and lastname), username and email addresses of persons. I need to get the names and email addresses and add them into an HTML table using regex (regular expressions).

The HTML table should look like this:

[image]

This is my javascript code so far:

```
// this is some example of the names & email adresses - they are fake
const outlook = "Anders Jensen (EAAAANJE) <eaaaanje@students.eaax.dk>; Bodil Pedersen (EAAABOPE) <eaaabope@students.eaax.dk>; Åse Andersen (EAAAIDAN) <eaaaasan@students.eaax.dk>; Mühl Svendsen (EAAAPESV) <eaaamusv@students.eaax.dk>";

// we find all the emails & names of the students
let regexEmail = /\<.*?\>/g;
let regexName = /\w+\s\w+\s/gi;

// an array of all the td-tags
let tdTags = document.querySelectorAll("td");

// The emails and names are inserted in the table
for(let i = 0; regexName.exec(outlook) !== null; i++) {

    tdTags[i].innerHTML = regexName.exec(outlook)[i]; // name
    tdTags[i].nextSibling.innerHTML = regexEmail.exec(outlook)[i]; // e-mail
}
```

The problem is it only prints the one name and insert it in the first td. And the e-mail adresses can't be retrieved. 
I'm still a beginner in Regex so I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Obligatory "don't use regex on HTML"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). If you actually have the name and email in separate cells, why not just get their text content from each cell?

Comment: I need to retrieve the names and e-mail adresses from a string and then insert them into the table

Comment: if your format is *always* the same for `firstName lastName (username) <emailAddress>;` then you should be able to look for the parens and brackets to find username and email.

Comment: @VLAZ: OP isn't parsing HTML using regex. Can you explain whats wrong in doing that? He's just constructing a simple HTML construct and its not that there are some nested tag complications here. I think you should not overuse discouragement the moment you hear HTML with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use a global `match()`. That will return just the strings captured. Then loop through that array of matches and use `exec()` on each individual user to separate out the name and email capture groups.

```js
const regex = /([^ ]+ [^ ]+) \(.*?\) <(.*?)>/g;

const outlook = "Anders Jensen (EAAAANJE) <eaaaanje@students.eaax.dk>; Bodil Pedersen (EAAABOPE) <eaaabope@students.eaax.dk>; Åse Andersen (EAAAIDAN) <eaaaasan@students.eaax.dk>; Mühl Svendsen (EAAAPESV) <eaaamusv@students.eaax.dk>";

const tbody = document.getElementById('users')
  .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
const users = outlook.match(regex);

users.forEach((user, index) => {
  const userRegex = /([^ ]+ [^ ]+) \(.*?\) <(.*?)>/;
  const userInfo = userRegex.exec(user);
  const row = tbody.insertRow(index);
  
  if (userInfo) {
    const nameCell = row.insertCell(0);
    const emailCell = row.insertCell(1);
    nameCell.innerHTML = userInfo[1];
    emailCell.innerHTML = userInfo[2];
  }
  
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="users">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `regexName.exec(outlook).length` is 1, so your loop is only ever going to run once. You might need to remove the matched string from `outlook` if you want to do it this way. However, I would suggest that you first split the `outlook` string by the `;` and then use the length of that array as your loop condition. Your regex is fine I believe

```
// this is some example of the names & email adresses - they are fake
const outlook = "Anders Jensen (EAAAANJE) <eaaaanje@students.eaax.dk>; Bodil Pedersen (EAAABOPE) <eaaabope@students.eaax.dk>; Åse Andersen (EAAAIDAN) <eaaaasan@students.eaax.dk>; Mühl Svendsen (EAAAPESV) <eaaamusv@students.eaax.dk>";

// we find all the emails & names of the students
let regexEmail = /\<.*?\>/g;
let regexName = /(\w+\s\w+\s)/gi;

// an array of all the td-tags
let tdTags = [];

let fragments = outlook.split(';');
// The emails and names are inserted in the table
for(let i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
  console.log(fragments[i])
  let name = fragments[i].match(regexName)
  let email = fragments[i].match(regexEmail)

  tdTags.push({ name, email: email });// e-mail
}
```

Comment: i have tried to run the loop 10 times where the run condition is: i < 10 but with the same result

Comment: Well the problem is you're getting the same result every time. Like I mentioned, you'd need to remove the matched string in every iteration OR split the string by the semi-colon and just match the element in the array. Either way should work

Answer (score -1):

Once you have a string I would be using something like:
    string.match(/\<(.*?)\>/g)[0]

Answer (score -1):

I know your question talks about regex, but I'd just use good old [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
// this is some example of the names & email adresses - they are fake
const outlook = "Anders Jensen (EAAAANJE) <eaaaanje@students.eaax.dk>; Bodil Pedersen (EAAABOPE) <eaaabope@students.eaax.dk>; Åse Andersen (EAAAIDAN) <eaaaasan@students.eaax.dk>; Mühl Svendsen (EAAAPESV) <eaaamusv@students.eaax.dk>";

// Get an array of the addresses by splitting on ;
const addresses = outlook.split(';').map(s => s.trim());
for (let address of addresses) {
  // Split each address on space
  const parts = address.split(' ');
  // the first two should be first and last name
  const name = `${parts[0]} ${parts[1]}`;
  // the fourth element should be the email address
  // remove the angle brackets
  const email = parts[3].replace(/(<|>)/g, '');
  // Do your table thing with the results
  console.log(name, email);
}
```